# Microsoft Azure | Internet Connection Problems

Tags: windows, centos, azure, internet, microsoft

I have 2 Virtual Machines on Microsoft Azure and I have the same problem with both of them... I can't use internet, when I want to open a site on Windows, it says 'This Site Can't Be Displayed' and I have Internet Explorer Enhanced Security off... On CentOS, I can't use internet too... When I ping a website it doesn't receive any data....
Here's an image from CentOS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeZRV.png

Comment: So I assume you are not connecting through **ssh** to the Linux box :-). Add the output of `ip -4 a` and `ip -4 route`.

Comment: i'm connecting through ssh...

Comment: Are you connecting through ssh to a machine with networking problems? What do the aforementioned commands give?